# A logic 0 can be a non-zero value (say upto 0.5volts), wouldn't that cause a current to flow through a device connected to output and then ground?

Tags: led

A current or no-current situation seems ideal to distinguish between a logic 1 and 0. But since logic 0 can be a non-zero volt, wouldn't that cause a current to flow through an external load connected to ground through a low value resistor or say, glow a low-current LED in both cases (0 and 1) as it will be forward-biased in both cases? If yes, then should we be aware of this fact and adjust circuits accordingly to distinguish precisely between a 0 and 1 logic (say, by making sure that LED doesnt light-up when output state is 0)? How exactly we should see a logic 0 compared to a logic 1?

Sorry if my question sounds too noob.

Comment: You are to a degree confusing current and voltage.  Current flows to *establish* both logic highs and logic lows when coming from the opposite state, as capacitance must be overcome.  Depending on what is being driven, current may need to continue to flow to keep either state.  Actual current-mode signaling systems do exist, often called "current loop".

Comment: Depends on the logic.  With old TTL most inputs "float" high and are "pulled" low by the driving output, so it doesn't much matter whether "low" is 0.5v or actually 0v -- the input will still detect it as "low".  And, as stated elsewhere, most logic technologies are voltage-driven, not current-driven.  The current can vary over a wide range with no change in behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But since logic 0 can be a non-zero volt, wouldn't that cause a current to flow through an external load connected to ground

In principle, yes. But usually the reason a logic output is above 0 V is because the external load is tied to a high voltage rather than to ground. So current in this scenario is flowing from the load to the logic gate's output rather than the other way around.

Consider these three circuits, and imagine the outputs of all 3 buffer gates are low:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOMktc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

BUF1 will not have a 0.5 V output voltage because its load is pulling current out of, rather than pushing current in to, the gate's output.

BUF2 might have a 0.5 V output, because its load is pushing current in. But this is arranged to light the LED for logic 0; having D2 lit is the expected and desired behavior.

BUF3 could also have a 0.5 V output, and this could cause a tiny leakage current to flow through D4, as suggested in your question. But current is not only leaking into R4 and D4, it's also flowing in to the BUF3 output pin. It isn't BUF3 that's providing the leakage current to D4, it's the pull-up path through D3 and R3.

Because the turn on voltage of D4 is almost certainly higher than 0.5 V, it is very unlikely that D4 will have a "lit" appearance.

> through a low value resistor or say, glow a low-current LED in both cases (0 and 1) as it will be forward-biased in both cases?

Most LEDs need at least 1.5 V before any substantial current flows through them and their output becomes visible. Some types might need as much as 2 V. So 0.5 V is not likely to lead to a visibly lit LED. If you were detecting the LED output with a very sensitive detector rather than just your eye, you might need to use a stronger output driver to be sure to turn the LED fully off.

> How exactly we should see a logic 0 compared to a logic 1?

The definitions depend on the logic family you're using. For example TTL and CMOS families have different definitions of what constitutes a valid 0 or 1.

If you're using a logic gate and load that can only produce 0.5 V in the low state, then any other logic inputs you connect to that output need to be chosen to be ones that will take 0.5 V as a valid low. For example, TTL logic has a typical switching threshold of 0.8 V, so if the input were 0.5 V, there wouldn't be much noise margin. In this case you might want to reduce the load current (the amount of current the first logic's output has to sink to produce the 0), or add a buffer, depending on circumstances.

Comment: "But usually the reason a logic output is above 0 V is because the external load is tied to a high voltage rather than to ground.", I am not clear with this. Isnt the non-zero LOW output created by the IC itself, say when a HIGH output is given to an inverter IC, a non-zero low is produced?
I am aware of pull-up resistor collecting (sinking) current at LOW state, but can you please clarify how is it relevant here.

Comment: It means the logic gate output has a particular I-V curve in the low state and in the high state. In the low state, if there is current flowing out of the gate, then the output voltage will be very close to 0 V, not as high as 0.5 V. To get the output voltage to be 0.5 V in the low state, you have to push current in to the output pin. If you just have an LED with series resistor tied to ground, this won't happen.

Comment: So does that mean that even in case of a logic HIGH (say 4v), the current flowing out of the gate will pull down the voltage to a low state? Or in general, any non-zero voltage at output is quickly drawn to low state after an instantaneous current flows when the output is connected to a load? I am so confused right now, I am sorry.

Comment: If the gate is outputting HI, and you pull enough current out of its pin to pull the voltage value to something that's a valid LOW state, then you've over-loaded or short-circuited the output. This is possible to do, but it's a bad design and likely to damge the chip. You need to reduce the current load on the output pin. For example by using a buffer chip or transistor.

Comment: I am trying the analogy of a simple circuit with a resistor and a battery, where the current conventionally flows from high potential on its one end to low potential on the other end, while the potential difference remains intact. But you said "if the current flows out, the voltage will be close to 0v" which is difficult for me to understand/relate.

Comment: Imagine the logic gate output is a 0V battery with a small internal resistance.

Comment: @Peace In an ideal world, the output would be 0V for logic low. But the output circuit is not perfect and if it's sinking some current (for example, if its output is connected to the positive supply through some equivalent resistance), its voltage will go up at least a little. To make sure our circuits work, we need to design them to tolerate the highest voltage we might see (where the output is sinking as much current as we need to allow) and still interpret that as a logic zero.

Answer (score 5):

For TTL chips the following picture might prove useful: -

[image]

On the right are the limits at which a logic 1 is defined for outputting devices. Note that it can range from 2.7 volts to 5 volts. Contrast this with what an input regards as a high level; it will accept a voltage level as low as 2 volts as a valid high level.

Same with logic 0 - the outputting device can produce 0.5 volts as a logic 0 but this will not register as a logic 1 because to do so it would need to exceed 2 volts at an input.

So, your logic circuits need to respect the voltage levels and they must not misconstrue what the levels mean. Here are CMOS logic levels: -

[image]

Let me count the ways....(not)

Comment: So basically, a discrete logic isn't exactly discrete behind the scenes but it is actually a range of voltages for HIGH and LOW logic?

Can you give some practical examples where this knowledge is used with extra care taken to make sure the two states dont mix-up?

Comment: @Peace, you might want to look up the term *noise margin* in a good digital logic textbook. Unfortunately the Wikipedia article on it is not much good.

Comment: Every family of logic chips and microprocessors use TTL or CMOS level conventions in the main. Some also use other conventions. I hope you don't mind if I don't list them but I do urge you to look them up.

Comment: @ThePhoton Duly noted. I will surely look into it and get back here. So far, I know that the noise margin is responsible for an IC to not work when the values of voltage are not in the defined regions, right? So, for a HIGH, it is the min voltage level of logic 1 and for a low, it is the maximum voltage of logic 0.

Comment: @Andyaka I wanted the guidance, which I got. I will go through the good articles to update my knowledge. Thanks

Comment: @Peace, the point of noise margin is, if you design the current to work with slightly non-ideal levels (like 0.5 V instead of 0 V for low), how much noise needs to be added to the system to produce an actually invalid input to the next gate.

Answer (score 4):

A chip that outputs logical values will have a section in its datasheet that states exactly which voltages are used to represent 0 and 1, for instance 0 .. 1.2 Volt for a 0. The device or circuit that is connecected to this output must be designed to handle the voltage level correctly.

A LED has a non-linear voltage-current graph, below a certain level it will hardly conduct any current at all. Luckily, that level is 1.5 .. 2.5 Volt for common LEDs, hence a LED can in most cases be connected directly to a digital output pin (with a suitable series resistor!).

Comment: "The device or circuit that is connected to this output must be designed to handle the voltage level correctly." this is exactly what I was looking for. So, every component is so precisely linked to other components after measuring the voltage acceptance levels for logic HIGH and LOW. This complicates the ideal understanding of digital logic for me, but I will try to absorb it.

Comment: To make this process less cumbersome, there are families of devices that have output levels that are compatible with their input levels. Andy's answer shows the output and input specifications for one such family, 5V CMOS. (But IMP the output levels he shows are overly optimistic).